# How to print out multiple items to output?

Tags: r, printing, console, formatting, stdio

I am a beginner in R, and currently for my output I use:

```
print("Hello World!")
```

However, I would like to give something like this out:

```
x <- 1
print("Hello World!" + x)#the + x does not
```

How can such a thing be coded in R?

I appreciate your answer!

Comment: I normally do `print(paste0("Hello World!", x))`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`cat`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/cat.html):

```
cat("Hello World!", x, '\n')
```

(Note the trailing `'\n'`, otherwise no newline character will be appended.)

Alternatively, you can combine the print statement with a [formatting statement (`sprintf`)](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sprintf.html);

```
cat(sprintf('Hello World!%s\n', x))
```

The formatting syntax of `sprintf` corresponds to that in C. The documentation linked above has more information.

Comment: Thx for your answer! Is is possible with `cat` to append more than one argument ,like: `cat("Hello", x "World!", y, '\n')`?

Comment: @user5414 Why not try it out?